# Python hashlib giving unexpected hash of some image files

Tags: python, hash, md5

I am trying to validate the md5 hashes of a bunch of files for a programing challenge. Most of the files are validating correctly (they all should). But on some jpg, png, and gif files the hash I am generating is not correct. Checking the files in terminal using md5sum yields the correct hash. This code shows how I am getting the md5 hash:

```
import hashlib
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3199/3083395581_663a7aaf76_z.jpg", "TestFile.jpg")
fileBytes = open("TestFile.jpg", 'rb').read()

foundHash = hashlib.md5(fileBytes).hexdigest()

print "Found Hash: " + foundHash
print "Expected Hash: abab4dd9a83f5636c10f4937686a7993"
```

Why is it not generating the correct md5?

Answer (score 0):

You get a different file using urllib.urlretrieve to retrieve the image than when downloading this image with a browser. Check the hash of the Python downloaded "TestFile.jpg" on the command line to see it's not the expected hash.

Check the source of your URL and that it adheres to the correct usage of the flickr API.

Comment: The TestFile.jpg does not have the same hash but I do not know about the flickr API. Are you saying that it could be the website not delivering the file correctly, or am I not receiving it correctly?

Comment: Flickr is returning either a (potentially dynamically created) 640px image or a 500px image, depending how the URL request is formed. For a quickfix, use another Python library to download your image which gets the 640px version, e.g. `requests`. To understand the issue you'll have to do a little research into how Flickr decides to return either image size - you'll need to find out how the `urlretrieve` request is different from e.g. a `wget` request to this URL.